# Display Bitmaps in Xamarin Forms created in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, bitmap, xamarin.forms

There are the Bitmap for Android and UIImage for iOS. Is there a way to display both somehow in the Xamarin Forms Image control?

Obviously I need the Dependency Service. I will have two implementations that create either a bitmap or an uiimage using some source, but how do I bring those two products together to a single forms control? Both Android and iOS methods have to return something, that the image control can understand and display. I don't know what that might be.

Edit: I look for a way where I don't use storage space, if possible.

Edit2:

I tried Jasons suggestion and it works fine.

I create a bitmap in the Android project and return a MemoryStream object:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
newImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
return stream;
```

Then I consume it in my Xamarin.Forms Image control:

```
var stream = DependencyService.Get<ICrossPlatformImageProcesor>().Combine_Images(imagePath);
stream.Position = 0;
img_ImageView.Source = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

Comment: turn your UIImage/Bitmap into a jpg/png and have Forms display it

Comment: @Jason Do you know a way to display it as an in-memory-object, without using storage space?

Comment: copy the data to a MemoryStream and use StreamImageSource

Answer (score 0):

> I will have two implementations that create either a bitmap or an uiimage using some source, but how do I bring those two products together to a single forms control?

You can simply use [Image Control](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Image/) of xamarin forms,  images can be loaded specifically for each platform, or they can be downloaded for display.

For more information, you can refer to [Working with Images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/).

> I look for a way where I don't use storage space, if possible.

I'm not quite understand this, if you mean don't use memory, then I think it is not possible. If you mean your images are not saved in storage, then possibly you have an URL address on internet of your images?

Anyway, Image control in Xamarin.Forms support image source form `ImageSource` instance, file, Uri, and resources, to load image from uri, you can simply code like this:

```
var webImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
webImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/forms/example-app.png"));
```